# Why is my bash script not recognizing the variable in the date command?

Tags: bash, positional-parameter

If I execute this line within a function of my bash script, it runs successfully:

```
function myFnc(){
...
variable1=$(date -d 2021-01-01 +%W)
...
}
```

But if I pass '2021' as input argument by running

```
myBash.sh '2021'
```

I get an error "date: date not valid #-01-01" if I replace the year with the corresponding variable:

```
function myFnc(){
...
variable1=$(date -d $1-01-01 +%W)
...
}
```

Also using quotes does not help:

```
function myFnc(){
...
variable1=$(date -d "$1-01-01" +%W)
...
}
```

Any idea on how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions in bash have their own argument list. As a consequence, they don't have access to the script's argument list.

You need to pass the argument to the function:

```
#!/bin/bash

# test.sh

myFnc() {
    variable1=$(date -d "${1}"-01-01 +%W)
    echo "${variable1}"
}

myFnc "${1}"
```

Now call the script like this:

```
bash test.sh 2021
```

---

Note: The `function` keyword in bash has no effect. It just makes the script unnecessarily incompatible with POSIX. Therefore I recommend not to use it.